# Название фирм в названии предметов

Tags: иностранные-слова

Правильно ли называть копировальный автомат ксероксом только потому, что самым известным производителем этих приборов стала фирма "Xerox"? И тоже самое с подгузниками "памперсами"? Или эти слова уже стали литературными?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ксерокс и памперс - фиксируются словарями как нарицательные. Так что - вполне нормально, если, конечно, речь не идет об официальных документах. Xerox, кстати, брать в кавычки не надо, латинское написание само по себе выполняет ту же функцию.

Answer (score 3):

Латинское написание - это неправильно для русского языка, как и для любого с иным алфавитом или письмом. Тогда надо писать джихад, шахид, халяль и т.д. по-арабски, китайские слова - по-китайски, да и вообще названия всех других стран и иностранных городов - на их языках. Кто-то в России будет понимать такие тексты? Вернитесь в на землю, Бегемот. Или тогда уж переходите на бегемотские слова. Ксерокс и памперс - только в русском языке эти жаргонизмы перекочевали в официальный язык. На иностранных: "ксерокс" - "фотокопия", а "памперс" - "подгузник".

Answer (score 0):

Нарицательными еще стали слова [скотч](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scotch_Tape), [лейкопластырь](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leukoplast) и пр. Просто начиная с какого-то момента времени продукция фирм под этими товарными знаками стала настолько ширпотребной, что перестало употребляется старое название, означающее сам тип предмета. Например, скотч - это ж липкая лента по сути. А ксерокс - ксерокопировальный аппарат. Новое слово оказалось более удачным и коротким, а частое его употребление и привело к изменениям в языке и замещению старого термина.